# Adding two dynamically generated HTML values together with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am creating a pricing interface that will ultimately yield two different prices for the user (experience + collection). I will need to then combine these prices in order to display a total price. The experience and collection prices are being displayed depending on the selections the user makes, and they currently work great.

But now I can't figure out how to add the html values of the two html elements. The class `total-cost` is where this added value should display. I've tried quite a few things in hopes of figuring it out myself, but no luck.

Thanks!

**HTML (cleaned up)**

```
<div class="pricing-experience">

    <div class="flex_column">
        <span class="cost1">3000</span>
    </div>

    <div class="flex_column">
        <span class="cost1">4000</span>
    </div>

    <div class="flex_column">
        <span class="cost1">5000</span>
    </div>

</div>


<div class="pricing-collection">

    <div class="flex_column">
        <span class="cost2">300</span>
    </div>

    <div class="flex_column">
        <span class="cost2">450</span>
    </div>

    <div class="flex_column">
        <span class="cost2">700</span>
    </div>

</div>


<div class="experience-cost">
//cost1's value
</div>

<div class="collection-cost">
//cost2's value
</div>

<div class="total-cost">
//cost1 and cost2's added value
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.pricing-experience, .pricing-collection').on('click', '.flex_column', function() {

    var experienceCost = $(this).find('.cost1').html(),
        collectionCost = $(this).find('.cost2').html();

    $(this).addClass('elephant').siblings().removeClass('elephant');

    // console.log(experienceCost);
    // console.log(collectionCost);

    $('.experience-cost').html(experienceCost);

    $('.collection-cost').html(collectionCost);

    $('.total-cost').html(experienceCost + collectionCost);

});
```

Comment: Can you show the html of the involved sections of your page?

Comment: Can you please post what experienceCost returns? HTML?

Comment: @LelioFaieta I have updated with the HTML.

Comment: @Mircea The post is updated!

Comment: There are 3 values .cost1 and 3 values .cost2. What do you want to add up?

Comment: @Mircea Users are able to select one experience and one collection. I want to add up the two html values that the user ends up picking and display the added value in the total_cost div. Hope that's clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

for each div with class `.cost1` and `.cost2` add value in a variable and then display it in div

JS:

```
$(".btn1").click(function () {

var experienceCost = 0;
var collectionCost = 0;
var totalCost = 0;
$('.cost1').each(function () {
    experienceCost += parseFloat($(this).text());
});
$('.cost2').each(function () {
    collectionCost += parseFloat($(this).text());
});

$('.experience-cost').text(experienceCost);
$('.collection-cost').text(collectionCost);
$('.total-cost').text(experienceCost + collectionCost);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pricing-experience">
<div class="flex_column"> <span class="cost1">3000</span>

</div>
<div class="flex_column"> <span class="cost1">4000</span>

</div>
<div class="flex_column"> <span class="cost1">5000</span>

</div>
</div>
<div class="pricing-collection">
<div class="flex_column"> <span class="cost2">300</span>

</div>
<div class="flex_column"> <span class="cost2">450</span>

</div>
<div class="flex_column"> <span class="cost2">700</span>

</div>
</div>
<div class="experience-cost"></div>
<div class="collection-cost"></div>
<div class="total-cost"></div>
<button class="btn1">experienceCost</button>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4eupw48/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the matching values on click:

```
var k=0, e=this;
while (e = e.previousElementSibling) { ++k;}
```

Here is a rough demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y3Ls4zso/1/

If I understood what you want to do here...