# Adding two dynamically generated HTML values together

Tags: jquery

*Asking this question a second time but providing much more detail this time around, providing a live example and asking a new question as well. The answers to my first question were irrelevant to my needs due to poor communication, and I still need help.*

I am creating a pricing interface that will ultimately yield in a user selecting two products (from a selection of 6 - mix & match), which will create two individual prices (one experience price and one collection price in this case). I will need to then combine these prices in order to display a total price. The experience and collection prices are being displayed depending on the selections the user makes just fine.

But now I can't figure out how to add the html values of the two html elements that the user selects. The class `total-cost` is where this added value should display. I've tried quite a few things in hopes of figuring it out myself, but no luck.

```js
//FOR SELECTING EXPERIENCE AND COLLECTION PACKAGES

$('.pricing-experience, .pricing-collection').on('click', '.flex_column', function() {

  var experienceCost = $(this).find('.cost1').html(),
    collectionCost = $(this).find('.cost2').html();

  $(this).addClass('elephant').siblings().removeClass('elephant');

  // console.log(experienceCost);
  // console.log(collectionCost);

  $('.experience-cost').html(experienceCost);

  $('.collection-cost').html(collectionCost);

  $('.total-cost').html(experienceCost + collectionCost);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pricing-experience">

  <div class="flex_column">
    <span class="cost1">3000</span>
  </div>

  <div class="flex_column">
    <span class="cost1">4000</span>
  </div>

  <div class="flex_column">
    <span class="cost1">5000</span>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="pricing-collection">

  <div class="flex_column">
    <span class="cost2">300</span>
  </div>

  <div class="flex_column">
    <span class="cost2">450</span>
  </div>

  <div class="flex_column">
    <span class="cost2">700</span>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="experience-cost">
  //cost1's value
</div>

<div class="collection-cost">
  //cost2's value
</div>

<div class="total-cost">
  //cost1 and cost2's added value
</div>
```

Comment: What happened with your previous question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding two dynamically generated HTML values together with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412189/adding-two-dynamically-generated-html-values-together-with-jquery)

Comment: @u_mulder I received two answer that were not inline with what I was looking for, unusable. The new question has been restructured to be more clear, provides a live example, provides more jQuery, and provides an additional question. I have also flagged my old question for deletion.

Comment: @Delto Generally a live jsFiddle is more useful, maybe you could consider adding that.

Comment: `experienceCost` is undefined which is why `totalCost` is never being calculated. Where do you set `cost1` and `cost2`?

Comment: @jcuenod `cost1` and  `cost2` are the elements that contain that numerical HTML values of the different packages. `cost1` is used for packages in the experiences options and `cost2` is used for the packages in the collections options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in your `click` event. `this` is scoped down to the element that is the target of the event. I've used your elephant class to find the selected elements so I've moved this line first:

```
$(this).addClass('elephant').siblings().removeClass('elephant');
var experienceCost = $('.elephant .cost1').html(),
    collectionCost = $('.elephant .cost2').html(),
    totalCost = parseInt(experienceCost, 10) + parseInt(collectionCost, 10);
```

A better way to do this would be to use global variables. Something like (untested):

```
var experienceCost, collectionCost;
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* your code */

    //I've invented the class "pricing_column" to improve this selector
    $(document).on('click', '.pricing_column .flex_column', function() {
        $(this).addClass('elephant').siblings().removeClass('elephant');
        if ($(this).hasClass("pricing-experience"))
        {
            experienceCost = $(this).find('.cost1').html()
        }
        else
        {
            collectionCost = $(this).find('.cost2').html()
        }
        //etc.
    }
})
```

Comment: Perfect, this did the trick! I will be researching your alternative method (still in the process of learning jQuery) and I'll hit you back with some feedback.  Thanks so much! Any way you could help me with the 'bonus' question I posted above?

Comment: Glad I could help! To be honest, for the sake of stackoverflow, you need to ask other questions, not just have discussions in the comments.

Comment: Okay, maybe I'll ask it in another question instead with a JSFiddle example. 

A quick question though... when you define a variable in the `click` event (such as `experienceCost` and `collectionCost`), does it save the data/information into the global variables with the same name? I ask this because I see that the global variables are only names. And then when I call the aforementioned global variables in different parts of my code, do they give me the html value (`cost1` in this case) to be used in other parts of my code so long as the relevant `click` event has been executed?

Comment: @Delto Take a look at http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Answer (score 1):

When you click on an option the "this" has either experienceCost or collectionCost - making the parseInt of the other to fail and the total cost become NaN.

Would advise having two variables outside the function and update them - or access the selection via proper selector instead of "this".